# SQL Join 2 tables with IDs in one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to join data from two tables into 1 row but i can't seem to figure out how to achieve this.

Table 1 structure

`id`, `name`, `number`, `email`

Table 2 structure

`id`, `friends`

The thing is in table 1, id is unique, whereas in table 2 `id` is not, he can have many friends. (Ofc this is all example).

I'm trying to get a row looking like this

`id`, `name`, `number`, `email`, `friend[1]`, `friend[2]` etc.

Any ideas how i can achieve this, or if i need to change my db structure to be able to get this result?

*Note (he only has a choice of 8 different friends).

Comment: Why do you think you need to get them all in one row? Any special requirement? Couldn't you do this on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way would be to group your results together with a JOIN statement;

```
SELECT T1.*, F1.Friend
FROM Table_1 as T1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 as F1
ON T1.id = F1.id
```

Then iterate through each of the rows in your mysql client.

Another way to do this is with multiple joins to the same table, but without a better way to distinguish the individual friend records you end up doing some messy exclusions in your JOIN statements.

```
SELECT T1.*, F1.Friend, F2.Friend, F3.Friend, [snip/] F8.Friend
FROM Table_1 as T1

LEFT JOIN Table_2 as F1
ON T1.id = F1.id AND F1.Friend NOT IN (F2.Friend, F3.Friend, [snip/] F8.Friend)

LEFT JOIN Table_2 as F2
ON T1.id = F2.id AND F2.Friend NOT IN (F1.Friend, F3.Friend, [snip/] F8.Friend)

LEFT JOIN Table_2 as F3
ON T1.id = F3.id AND F3.Friend NOT IN (F1.Friend, F2.Friend, F4.Friend, [snip/] F8.Friend)

[big snip/]

LEFT JOIN Table_2 as F8
ON T1.id = F8.id AND F8.Friend NOT IN (F1.Friend, F2.Friend, [snip/] F7.Friend)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered implementing group_concat? (http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/)

Regardless of the fact that there would only be 8 friends per user, it isn't practical/efficient solution to generate columns based on joined rows.